# How to use Lock Component in Symfony3.4 with username

Tags: symfony, locking, symfony-lock

I am trying to use the lock component in symfony 3.4, like it is described on
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/lock.html

I want to prevent multiple data changes from different users.

For example user1 is calling the same company form with data, then user2

**How can I tell user2, that editing data is blocked by user1 (incl username) ?**

**UPDATE:**
It is used in backend, where a lot of employees editing data of customers, order etc.
this form is just for editing. that means, if they want to update some data, they click "edit". They should be informed when another employee changes this record before the data is loaded into the form. It sometimes takes some time for the employee to change everything. If the employee receives a message when saving it, they have to go back,reload the data and start all over again.

an example out of my controller:

```
 public function CompanyEdit(Request $request)
    {

        $error = null;
        $company_id                                 = $request->get('id');
//        if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/', $company_id)){
//            return $this->showError();
//        }

        $store = new SemaphoreStore();
        $factory = new Factory($store);
        $lock = $factory->createLock('company-edit-'.$company_id, 30);

        if(!$lock->acquire()) {
             //send output with username
            // this data is locked by user xy
            return 0;
        }

        $company = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Company::class)->find($company_id);
        $payment = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Companypay::class)->findOneBy(array('company_id' => $company_id));

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('company', CompanyFormType::class, array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Company',
                'data' => $company
            ))
            ->add('payment', CompanyPayFormType::class, array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\CompanyPay',
                'data' => $payment

            ))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $company = $form->get('company')->getData();
        $payment = $form->get('payment')->getData();

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);

            if ($payment->getCompanyId() == null) {
                $payment->setCompanyId($company->getId());
            }

            try {
                $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($company);
                $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($payment);
                $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
                $this->container->get('app.logging')->write('Kundendaten geändert', $company->getId());
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
            }
            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {

                return $this->render('customer/edit.html.twig', [
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'company' => $company,
                    'error' => $error,
                    'success' => true
                ]);
            }
            $lock->release();
            return $response;
        }
```

Comment: Why would you block users to even view a form? What do you want to achieve? (see my answer, I think this is a XY Problem)

Comment: see update. they should be informed before edit something.

Comment: You can't use the Lock Component for this. I can't contain metadata. And even if you could: you're creating a Lock which is released after 30 seconds. Not what you want, I expect?

Comment: the above couls is an example where I stopped at last. I did it in both ways. with and without releasetime. the blocking did not work. the form can be called to times from different users at the sametime.

Comment: Again: there is no way you can add information to a Lock, such as a username. And if you get it to work, the first user can't submit the form within 30 seconds, but another user can still view the page after 30 seconds if the first user is still making changes. Your solution will never work.

Comment: This question can't be answered. The given solution (using Lock Component) just cannot solve the real problem. This is a typical XY-problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (Locks can't have any metadata), but you probably don't want this in the first place.

In this case, you create a Lock when a user opens the edit page and release it when a user submits the form. But what if the users opens the page and doesn't submit the form? And why can't a user even view the form?

This looks like a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I think you're trying to prevent users to overwrite data without knowing. Instead, you can add a timestamp or hash to the form that changes after changing the entity. For example:

```
<form type="hidden" name="updatedAt" value="{{ company.updatedAt()|date('U') }}" />
```

And in your form:

```
<?php
if ($company->getUpdatedAt()->format('U') !== $form->get('updatedAt')->getData()) {
    throw new \LogicException('The entity has been changed after you opened the page');
}
```

Disclaimer: code is not tested and just as an example how this solution can look like.

Comment: Sorry. this form is just for editing, not for viewing. See Update above